# deep learning prediction model which is taking 1hour per GB with 8 CPUs

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am running a deep learning prediction model which is taking 1hour per GB with 8 CPUs. I have lot of data preprocessing using regular expressions, data cleaning before feeding the data to the ANN model. I am looking to reduce the run time. Can anyone suggest, if GPUs can help or adding more CPUs could be helpful?

If GPU is required , can you help me with details (type,cores) so that i can request the infra team to arrange for it.

Thanks in advance!!
Regards,
Ravi

i am using 8 cpus to run the Deep learning prediction.

Comment: No, no one can help if you don't show your code. Have you profiled it to see where it's spending it time?

Comment: (Also, on a similar note, have you verified that all 8 CPUs are being maxed out?)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Ravi. Ever since the early 2010's, GPUs have been the bread and butter of machine learning, almost no serious models run or train without them in a reasonable amount of time. As for recommendations for GPUs, really it depends on what you're trying to do, how big your model is, how many of them you're trying to run at once... Figure out how much VRAM your model demands and go from there. Make sure that whatever you buy is CUDA enabled.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely CPU is not your solution, and you can not get that much of a chance to increase the time performance of training by adding more CPUs. You need to train your model on GPU-based systems.
Any GPU that you can afford would be helpful. RTX 4090, RTX 4080, RTX 3090 ti, and RTX 6000, etc would be some suggestions, but they are just suggestions you can go for other options. For sure, if you spend more money, you can get more powerful system and much better performance for your training. If GPU is not affordable for you, you can use Kaggle (or any others like google-colab, etc), and get access to free GPU for a specific amount of time per week to train your model there (google it to see how to activate the free Kaggle GPU), BUT, there are some limitations that you have to read about them.

Comment: Good answer, but I feel like it's important to note that not just any GPU will work, it must be CUDA enabled.